# Cannot find name T

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why I get this error ?

```
Cannot find name T
```

Code:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  type person<T> = {
    name: T,
    age?: T
  };
  
  let arr: T[] = [];
  
  const addPerson = (person: T): void => {
    arr.push(person);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => addPerson({name: 'James'})}>Hello World</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did those periods at the end of your question have any significance, or did you just add them to meet the minimum requirement for % of your question not being code?

Comment: `T` is a generic type, and your not passing anything to it.  And why you would want the same type for `name & age` seems odd.    Your maybe best explaining what your trying to do, as the code just doesn't make much sense at the momement.

Comment: Because `T` is not in scope.  Do you understand JavaScript?  If so, then it's the same reason [this doesn't work](https://tsplay.dev/w2488m).

Answer (score 0):

The `T` is only in scope from where it was defined until the end of that statement.  It doesn't have any meaning after that.  It also appears you don't know what generics are or how to use them.  The `person` type you have declared takes a generic argument, that argument is a type, and it's declaring that a person has a name and an optional age, which both must be of that type, which clearly doesn't make sense for most types.

Give what you are doing, you don't need the generics at all, you probably just want:

```
function App() {
  type person = {
    name: string,
    age?: number
  };
  
  let arr: person[] = [];
  
  const addPerson = (person: person): void => {
    arr.push(person);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => addPerson({name: 'James'})}>Hello World</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```